# Win10- How do you boot into the repair screen manually?

Tags: windows-10

When windows 10 can't boot up it will go to the repair screen  but how do I get to it manually. There's perhaps a keyboard shortcut I need to hit on bootup, if so, what is it?

i'm talking about this screen

[image]

Comment: There isn't one. Your choices are listed here [Advanced Startup Options - Boot to in Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2294-advanced-startup-options-boot-windows-10-a.html). None of them involve a single key press during a normal boot.

Comment: Pressing a key to access your firmware settings has not been possible since Windows supported, Fast Startup, which is the reason Advanced Startup exists.  Windows will also by itself boot to the Advanced Startup environment if it fails to boot three times.

Comment: See Option six in the link DavidPostill commented.

Comment: @Moab thanks.. do you think that's possibly had for the hard drive? e.g. would it always dismount if I held power? I've found when holding power it always turns off after some constant small number of seconds like 2 seconds or 3 seconds, I wonder if the hard drive always dismounts before then.. I guess perhaps not. In contrast, shutting down via an option,  can take a while longer.

Comment: See my answer, it works.

Comment: @Moab i'm aware that it works, it has been mentioned already, I wasn't saying it didn't work. And the reason why I accepted masgo's answer is because he mentioned that technique first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers it: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode

The simplest way is to hold down the Shift key while clicking on restart, that brings up the "Choose an option" screen

**Edit by barlop**

The answerer points out in comment, that

to the direct question of booting in without going into windows and finding a way to restart such that it goes on,   he's only seen that (directly going in), in a dual boot scenario when he had windows 10 technical preview. It may be possible to customize win10 setup to produce that.

Aside from that, the closest is booting from a Windows 10 USB /DVD

Or power on the pc - power it off (by holding down the power button) while windows is still starting - repeat 3 times, then windows will recognize it as "boot failure" and go to the repair screen".

Comment: I said boot into it. Not go into windows and then fine a way to restart it such that it goes in.

Comment: There is no way! Only options are: 1) use a windows USB-stick or DVD or 2) power on the pc - power it off (by holding down the power button) while windows is still starting - repeat 3 times, then windows will recognize it as "boot failure" and go to the repair screen" ... except for this: no other options if you have a "standard" windows 10 setup

Comment: that is  a very useful comment that addresses things more directly... And are there any non standard windows 10 setups that do / cna you elaborate on any?

Comment: If you have a Dual-Boot windows setup (I only had that when using the technical previews) then you can choose "other options" to get to the recovery modes. I have also seen laptops which had an UEFI BIOS which allowed to boot into a recovery mode (which was specific to the brand) which then allowed to boot into windows recovery. Also if you have Windows/Linux dual boot you can get into recovery (but i have not used this myself).

Comment: a minor nitpick of your last comment, there's no such thing as UEFI BIOS.  BIOS is replaced by UEFI.. BIOS isn't a general term in that it doesn't include UEFI.

Comment: This might be seen as nitpicking but the edit, reads really really rough, its almost not comprehensible.  If the base answer has more substance I would fix it myself.

Comment: See Option six in the link DavidPostill commented, you do not have to boot into a usb stick or dvd.

Comment: @Moab see the answer and the comments preceding yours and they all mention the 3 power on/offs

Answer (score 3):

When you cannot load windows so you can configure it to get the advanced screen on next boot try this.

Power up and wait for the blue windows screen with the spinning circle, when you see that press and hold power button to shut down, after shutdown power back up and do the same thing again, power up for the 3rd time and you should get repair screen.

This is  when you power off, be sure the spinning circle is present before power down.

[image]

Do this power cycle twice and on the third time you will get an auto repair screen
[image]

Let the auto repair run

[image]

When it is done you will get a screen to enter advanced options

[image]

Credits to DavidPostill for the link in his comment, [source of this answer](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2294-advanced-startup-options-boot-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: the guy that wrote the accepted answer mentioned that method in comment even before david postil gave the link where you then found point 6 that described that. That said, it's a great link and point 6 was well found

Comment: a)I put his comment in his answer already.  b)elaborating on somebody's comment by making an answer, saying it and adding screenshots is not such an impressive/worthy thing, it's not worthless but it's nothing worth a "well done". Also, If I had a win10 machine in front of me then I would try it and see how necessary/useful those screenshots are, or whether they're just padding and if it was pretty idiot proof without them, but I don't right now so I can't judge them,

Comment: If anything i'd normally encourage the person making the comment to make an answer of it then I might edit and improve their answer, rather than making an answer myself.  And if I had anything to add e.g. do it when there's a circle, then i'd make it a comment or edit   their answer and add that note.

Comment: @ Moab if you can't quote a specific line and state why you think it's a load of crap, then i'm not interested and there's no point in you giving your opinion(if you're not backing it up with argument, which you didn't in your last comment where you wrote "a load of crap my friend"),

Comment: You are just repeatedly saying it's crap, and now making an analogy to dog poop, you are not saying anything informative, and are essentially trolling.