# Windows 10 fails to boot after update

Tags: windows, windows-10, multi-boot, windows-update

My computer fails to boot into the Windows 10 OS after the recent update. It just goes into the windows loading screen and just goes blank after few seconds and stays there for few more seconds and simply restarts.

- I don't have a way for safe mode boot.
- I tried creating a recovery USB disk and tried auto recovery. Auto recovery failed, Looks like it doesn't even know where the OS is.
- I tried doing system restore to the earlier point that ended up with the error "system restore error 0x80070003".

I'm afraid my system is completely corrupted. I tried to launch command prompt from the same recovery menu, to my surprise I see the C, D and E volumes got interchanged I see all the data present in D drive is now in C (Obviously the drives got swapped), C is moved to E and E is now D.

Machine is actually configured with dual boot of Windows 10 along with Ubuntu. Ubuntu works just fine.

I did nothing but accepting the update from the windows.

I will lose a lot of important software and the configurations I had if I lose my OS.

Comment: I'm able to copy the data to an external drive through that command prompt. I'm just taking backup of few important data as a precautionary measure.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "the most recent update" are speaking of a cumulative update or a feature update like 1803?  Why is this tagged as "Windows 10 Upgrade" when it doesn't appear to be related to upgrading to WIndows 10?

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that I'm actually tagging windows10 upgrade instead of update tag.

Comment: I'm not really sure about the build number or feature number. I did click the update button likewise I usually do trusting that it would be done properly.

Comment: Why don't you *have a way for safe mode boot*? Just press F8 immediately after selecting Windows in Grub menu. And make sure you're booting the recovery media in the same mode the OS is installed (probably and hopefully UEFI). The tool not finding the OS and drive letters changing is typical of booting in Legacy mode.

Comment: I did not configure Safemode boot in the windows 10 before. I have found a way to do so. I will try the same.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/ssd-hard-drive-no-recognized-after-crashing/c7bcdfb4-17ff-4a41-8c22-1cbfbef301d1, this one looks similar to the problem that I'm facing right now.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia , I'm not able to boot into safemode either. It just loops for sometime and goes blank and restarts :(

Comment: Now I can boot into safe mode, It fails half of the time though. At least I'm able to access something. I get  black screen when I try to restore to a previous restore point.

Comment: @Ramhound the update ID is KB4459377 . I'm unable to uninstall the update. I'm getting "Update for Microsoft Windows (KB4459377) is required by your computer and cannot be uninstalled" error.

Comment: @Ram - I cannot find any mention of KB4459377, anywhere, you sure that is the update that was installed?  Knowing what feature build, you had installed, would help identify the patch.

Comment: Thank god, I booted into recovery mode by pressing shift key and rebooting from lock screen and uninstalled the latest feature and quality updates from windows. That solved my problem.

Comment: For future events See my post here to get a repair screen...https://superuser.com/a/1067792/40928

Comment: Try to use a USB disk to boot system into USB ISO iamge.Then go into WinRe and try system recovery to check.